# plugin installing error

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Actually I have facing issue is site taking too much time to get data from datatable in WordPress.

Also, when I try installing any plugin, I get the error below:

> An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.

So my question is when I'm trying to install any plugin that can't install any plugin.

What is the issue and how can I resolve it so as to install the plugin successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an internet connectivity issue.

Do check an make sure you have a stable connection, then try installing your plugin again; it should work.